# IE performance problem (long send request time)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, performance, internet-explorer, httpwebrequest

Subject: ASP.NET web application

Action: from client(IE web browser) sent sync http request(using javascript) to server (to ASP.NET web app)

Problem: from time to time request takes too long (20 - 50 seconds)

With IE 9 developers tools I performed testing (results on screenshot)

http://oi51.tinypic.com/mav6fb.jpg

You can see 16 seconds duration - for period between request was initialy created to when the request is sent. 
Why is soo long?
How I can control this?

Thanks for answers
( Sorry for my English =)

Comment: @Vitaliy. My dear in request What are you sending.... Your parameters?

Comment: What exactly you need? Request body, Headers, Response body?

Comment: I want to say it's reproduced not always only from time to time (like every 1 from 5 requests)

Comment: @Vitaliy. Send your whole body, header and response

Comment: https://rapidshare.com/files/458329794/Params.txt

Comment: sorry for Rapishare - file is too big for posting here

Comment: Screen for last request(32 seconds to start !!!) - http://oi51.tinypic.com/ay7c4m.jpg

Comment: I expérience the same exact problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/34796784/99276. My request payload is really small (few bytes) . But the PUT requests take ages to be sent. I have not this probleme with other browsers