# Http requests slower with IE

Tags: javascript, http, internet-explorer, networking, request

Working on my javascript app I have noticed the same ajax request is up to 10 times longer with IE(11).

Response size are strictly identical (12.6KB).

the only differences I see are these :

- IE adds Pragma: no-cache; not chrome.
- Chromes accepts sdch and not IE

As you can see on screenshots below, server processing time, and data transfert are quite the same on both browsers, but this "start" time is huge on IE and can be up to 500ms!

You will notice host is localhost. Is DNS lookup involved?

Measuring with Fiddler lead to same results.

Can you help me to explain this?!

Edit : localhost server is IIS7, server side ASP.net Web Api services access C++ COM objects through Interops

[image]

[image]